# Angular 7/Electron: Routing does not complete after BrowserWindow.hide followed by BrowserWindow.show

Tags: angular, typescript, electron, angular2-routing

I have an Angular 7 application that runs in an Electron window. The Electron process in `main.ts` must do the following:

1. `main.ts`: Show window + load url to Angular app
2. Angular: does its thing
3. Angular: uses ipcRenderer to tell main process that it's temporarily done
4. `main.ts`: BrowserWindow.hide()
5. `main.ts`: Does other
6. `main.ts`: BrowserWindow.show()
7. `main.ts`: `mainWindow.webContents.send('route', '/myroute');`
8. Angular: `this.ipcRenderer.on('route', (event: any, route: string) => {         this.router.navigateByUrl(route); });`

**Expected behavior**: the window hides, then is shown and shows the new component.

**Actual behavior**: the window hides, then is shown and shows a partially loaded component followed by the previous route's (e.g. entrypoint) component.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

<route component imports>

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/entrypoint', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'entrypoint', component: EntryPointPageComponent },
    { path: 'myroute', component: MyRouteComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '/entrypoint' }
];

@NgModule({
    exports: [ RouterModule ],
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true }) ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {
    constructor(private router: Router) {
        this.router.events.subscribe((value) => {
            console.log(`Router event! ${ typeof value}: ${ value }`);
        }, (err) => {
            console.log(`Router failure! ${ err }`);
        });
    }
}
```

When it's time to go route to `/myroute`, I see the following events go through, in this order: `NavigationStart`, `RoutesRecognized`, `GuardsCheckStart`, `ChildActivationStart`, `ActivationStart`, `GuardsCheckEnd`, `ResolveStart`, `ResolveEnd`, `ActivationEnd`, `ChildActivationEnd`, `NavigationEnd`, `Scroll`.

Finally, I implemented all of the event lifecycles in `MyRouteComponent` with console log statements, but none of them get executed.

Any ideas what the issue is that's preventing routing from working successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were able to resolve this internally and now I feel dumb.

The trick was to wrap the routing request inside `ngZone.run()`.